# Node js - Sequelize - Destroy several selected ids by one push

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have issue with multi delete:

```
   export const deleteProducts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const ids = req.params.ids
  
    await Product.destroy({
      where: {
        id: ids
      }
    });
    res.json({
      message: "ProductS Deleted",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

when I send request with ID's array to this function for example

```
http://localhost:5000/products/deleteByIds/535,536.537
```

function delete from mySQL only one first ID,
But in log I see this:

```
Executing (default): DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `id` IN ('535,536,537')
```

when I try this like that -

```
export const deleteProducts = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const ids = [535,536,537]
      
        await Product.destroy({
          where: {
            id: ids
          }
        });
        res.json({
          message: "ProductS Deleted",
        });
      } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message });
      }
    };
```

everything working

```
Executing (default): DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `id` IN (535, 536, 537)
```

where I make mistake?

Comment: 535,536.537 --> there is a dot (.) after 536.
 

you need to put these ids in a array and then perform delete operation

Comment: What do you get when you console.log req.params.ids?

Answer (score 1):

req.params.ids is of type string.

You need to put the ids in an array, then perform the delete operation

you can convert the ids in an array following ways

```
const ids = req.params.ids.split(',');
```

Hope it'll fix your issue.